# How to use transaction on more than one entities in Google Cloud Plateform using Objectify?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, transactions, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I have `Entity1` and `Entity2`, their Manager respectively `NewQManager` and `QAManager` and Services `QAService` and `NewQService`.
 
**What I want to do**: I want to remove Question from `Entity1` and add it to `Entity2` in a single transaction, for that, I am using Objectify services in `AbstractTransaction` class which is extended by `QAService`. However, I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: operating on too many entity groups in a single transaction.
```

**QuestionManager.java**

```java
QAService.getInstance().implementTransaction(
        repo -> {
        NewQManager.getInstance().remove(question);
        QAManager.getInstance().addOrUpdateItem(question);
            return true;
        });
```

**QAService.java**

```java
public class QAService extends AbstractTransaction {
    public static QAService getInstance() {
        if (instance != null)
            return instance;

        instance = new QAService();
        return instance;
    }
}
```

**AbstractTransaction.java**

```java
public class AbstractTransaction<T, ID> {

    public <A> A implementTransaction(Function<AbstractTransaction<T, ID>, A> operations) {
        return ofy().transact(() -> operations.apply(this));
    }

    public T save(T entity) {
        ofy().save().entity(entity).now();
        return entity;
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: operating on too many entity groups in a single transaction.
        at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper.translateError(DatastoreApiHelper.java:52)
        at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper$1.convertException(DatastoreApiHelper.java:135)
        at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:109)
        at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Batcher$ReorderingMultiFuture.get(Batcher.java:115)
        at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.FutureHelper$TxnAwareFuture.get(FutureHelper.java:186)
        at com.googlecode.objectify.cache.TriggerFuture.get(TriggerFuture.java:100)
        at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.ResultAdapter.now(ResultAdapter.java:34)
        at com.googlecode.objectify.util.ResultWrapper.translate(ResultWrapper.java:22)
        at com.googlecode.objectify.util.ResultWrapper.translate(ResultWrapper.java:10)
        at com.googlecode.objectify.util.ResultTranslator.nowUncached(ResultTranslator.java:21)
        at com.googlecode.objectify.util.ResultCache.now(ResultCache.java:30)
        at com.googlecode.objectify.util.ResultWrapper.translate(ResultWrapper.java:22)
        at com.googlecode.objectify.util.ResultWrapper.translate(ResultWrapper.java:10)
        at com.googlecode.objectify.util.ResultTranslator.nowUncached(ResultTranslator.java:21)
        at com.googlecode.objectify.util.ResultCache.now(ResultCache.java:30)
com.vivoiz.healofy.backend.commonServices.services.AbstractTransaction.save(AbstractTransaction.java:44)
```

Answer (score 1):

All this AbstractTransaction stuff looks weird and the extra complexity is probably hiding what you are doing.

One of the fundamental limits of the datastore is you can only enlist 25 entity groups in a single transaction. Somehow you are doing that, possibly by @Load groups - it's impossible to tell from what you've posted.

The solution is "load less stuff in your transaction".